# Making a dictionary from each line in a file

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I am trying to make a dictionary from this file: with the key being the first word, and the values being all words afterwards.

```
andrew fred
fred
judy andrew fred
george judy andrew
john george
```

This is the code I have:

```
follows_file = open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Python\\follows.txt")
followers = {}
for line in follows_file:   #==> [Judy Andrew Fred]
    users = line.split(' ')     #==> [Judy, andrew, Fred, ....]
    follower = users[0]     #==> [Judy]
    followed_by = users[1:] #==> [Andrew, Fred]

    for user in followed_by:
        # Add the 'follower to the list of followers user
        if user not in followers:
            followers[user] = []
        followers[user].append(follower)
print(followers.items())
```

When I print the *follower* and *followed by* variable, they are correct, but i'm having trouble adding them into the dictionary correctly; with this being the output

```
dict_items([('fred\n', ['andrew', 'judy']), ('andrew', ['judy']), ('judy' ['george']), ('andrew\n', ['george']), ('george', ['john'])])
```

My desired output would be

```
(Andrew[Fred])(Fred[])(judy[Andrew Fred])(George[Judy Fred])(john[george])
```

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: Use `line.split()` to get rid of all the whitespace, including the newlines.

Comment: At least you forgot to strip newlines, so you have `('andrew', ['judy'])` and `('andrew\n', ['george'])` separately.

Comment: [You're not allowed to vandalize your own questions if they're helpful to somebody else](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306820/is-defacing-own-posts-worth-a-mod-flag). If you keep doing it there will be automatic moderator flags. Please roll back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited answer, improved thanks to the comments from @PM2Ring and @IljaEverilä.**

Here is my original solution using a dictionary comprehension

```
followers = {line.split()[0]: line.split()[1:] for line in follows_file}
```

A more efficient alternative proposed by @IljaEverilä, which avoids calling `split` twice, is:

```
followers = {follower: followees for follower, *followees in map(str.split, follows_file)}
```

Result:

```
{'andrew': ['fred'],
 'fred': [],
 'george': ['judy', 'andrew'],
 'john': ['george'],
 'judy': ['andrew', 'fred']}
```

Note that both of the above solutions assume that your file contains no duplicate keys.

Don't forget to close your file afterwards:

```
follows_file.close()
```

Or better, just use a context manager, which handles the file closing for you:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\zacan\\Desktop\\Python\\follows.txt', 'r') as follows_file:
    followers = {follower: followees for follower, *followees in map(str.split, follows_file)}
```

Comment: Why call `.strip()` on a string that you're passing to `.split()`? And why perform that expensive operations twice on every line? Use a proper `for` loop so you don't need to do that.

Comment: `{follower: followees for follower, *followees in map(str.split, f)}`

Comment: @PM2Ring - I hadn't realised that `split()` took care of the trailing `\n` for each line, will edit the `strip()` calls out of my answer. @IljaEverilä, nice, I was trying to think of a way to do a comprehension without calling `split()` twice, but hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as a dictionary factory and just append the users following a person, e.g.:

```
import collections

followers = collections.defaultdict(list)  # use a dict factory to save some time on checks
with open("path/to/your_file", "r") as f:  # open the file for reading
    for line in f:  # read the file line by line
        users = line.split()  # split on any white space
        followers[users[0]] += users[1:]  # append the followers for the current user
```

Which will produce, for your data:

```
{'andrew': ['fred'],
 'fred': [],
 'judy': ['andrew', 'fred'],
 'george': ['judy', 'andrew'],
 'john': ['george']}
```

This will also allow you to have multiple lists appended to the user on a repeating record - otherwise you can just use a normal `dict` for `followers` and set them as `followers[users[0]] = users[1:]`.

The data structure you've shown as your desired output is not valid Python, do you really want it presented that way? I mean, if you insist you can do it as:

```
print("".join("({}[{}])".format(k, " ".join(v)) for k, v in followers.items()))
# (andrew[fred])(fred[])(judy[andrew fred])(george[judy andrew])(john[george])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution using `str.split` and a `try` / `except` clause to capture instances where only a key exists.

Note [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) lets us read from a string as if it were a file.

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

mystr = StringIO("""andrew fred
fred
judy andrew fred
george judy andrew
john george""")

# replace mystr with open("C:\\Users\\zacan\\Desktop\\Python\\follows.txt")
with mystr as follows_file:
    d = {}
    for users in csv.reader(follows_file):
        try:
            key, *value = users[0].split()
        except ValueError:
            key, value = users[0], []

        d[key] = value

print(d)

{'andrew': ['fred'],
 'fred': [],
 'george': ['judy', 'andrew'],
 'john': ['george'],
 'judy': ['andrew', 'fred']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
followers = dict()
with open('C:\\Users\\zacan\\Desktop\\Python\\follows.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        users = line.split(' ')
        followers[users[0]] = [_ for _ in users[1:]]
```

this should work, didn't test it

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to do list comprehension when setting the value of user followers. Also, `line.split(' ')` will produce the last user in line with a `\n` added to it, or register a new followed user with a `\n` as its last character.